# Вставка темплейтов для компиляции в index.html

Tags: jquery, javascript, frontend

Добрый день!
Только Frontend!
Например, есть темплейты, которые должны встраиваться в основной файл:

```
templates/template1.html
templates/template2.html
index.html
```

С помощью чего можно подключить темплейты в index.html?
Расширение в темлейтах не важно, главное подключить, для компиляции с помощью шаблонизатора.
Есть способ, $('#container').load('path/to/file'), но дело в том, что он будет подгружать их после того, как произойдет $(document).ready(). Есть ли более быстрый способ?

Comment: Что у вас за шаблонизатор который этого не умеет? Любой приличный умеет

Comment: @donkey, какие, например?

Comment: @idd у меня тут вот есть недоделанный немного шаблонизатор: nodesmarty.com можно и файлы конфигурации подключать и инклюды делать и переменные вставлять.